# Mapping existing file against a new content type

Tags: 7, files, nodes

I am facing a situation here.

I have a content type A with an image field(field_upload_snaps) in it. There is another content type B which also contains an image field(field_valid_snaps).

Now user will upload the pics from A content type. So if user upload 3 pics via A then 3 FID and their corresponding URIs will be created in file_managed table in Drupal 7.

Now I have a requirement where I have to insert 2 images out of 3 programatically using Drupal code. Now there is no need to generate any new image copy in public URI as images already exist via A.

I tried two approaches:-

1) I have created a new node of Type B. I tried to fetch file URI,filesize,filemime and all relevant parameter from existing fid and associate with the node using this.

```
 global $user;
 $node = new stdClass();
 $node->type = "user_slideshow_snaps";
 $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
 node_object_prepare($node);
 $node->uid = $user->uid;
 $file = (object) array(
  'uid' => $user->uid,
  'uri' => 'public://1.jpeg" ,
  'filemime' => 'image/jpeg',
  'status' => 1,
 ); 

 $node->field_upload_snaps['und'][] = (array)$file;
 $node = node_submit($node); // Prepare node for a submit
 node_save($node);
```

But it gives me an error that "Cant insert duplicate value in file_managed". It will give because such value already exist in file_managed via A. So I am not able to save value.

2) I saved node first and then manually insert in the image field like this.

```
 global $user;
 $node = new stdClass();
 $node->type = "user_slideshow_snaps";
 $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
 node_object_prepare($node);
 $node->uid = $user->uid;
 $node = node_submit($node); // Prepare node for a submit
 node_save($node);

 db_insert('field_data_field_valid_snaps')
    ->fields(array(     
    'entity_type' => 'node',
    'bundle' => 'user_actualD_snaps',
    'deleted'=> 0,
    'entity_id'=>$node->nid,
    'delta'=>0,
    'field_valid_snaps_fid'=>517,
    'field_valid_snaps_alt'=>'',
    'field_valid_snaps_title'=>'',
    'field_valid_snaps_width'=>200,
    'field_valid_snaps_height'=>300, 
    ))
    ->execute();
```

But the line after node_save() doesnt execute in this case. So I am not able to save it.

Are there any functions available which will map existing images into another table?

Answer (score 0):

I think the [File Field sources](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources) module will solve your problem.  (The D7 version works directly with the core *Field* module).  It will, among other things, allow you to re-use files by an auto-complete textfield.

Btw: Any file appearing in `file_managed` can only appear once in that table, so you should not be allowed to do what you try to do in your first approach.

Comment: Will there be any logic references to create a new node from existing saved file. I want PHP code to do this stuff as I did it for 2 approaches. If there are any other suggestion other than going for custom module then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

File_load API solved my problem of getting the dimensions of existing file and save in another content type.